# C command-line parser for handling comments

Tags: c, parsing, getopt, command-line-arguments

I have a `tool` that takes `input` and makes `output`:

```
$ tool input > output
```

I'd like to add an option that is a long string — say, a "comment" option. This comment text is an argument to the option and is a sentence enclosed in forward tick marks:

```
$ tool --comment='I am commenting on the use of comments' input > output_plus_comment
```

This is different from the usual `--foo=bar` key-value pairing, where `foo` is the option name and `bar` is a one-word value (e.g., `true`, `red`, ...).

Is there a good command-line parser library for C that handles this particular case?

Comment: Yes, `getopt`. It should work literally with the command line you provided.

Comment: Might you have any examples of how this is done? The documentation seems a bit threadbare for this case: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html

Comment: There are millions of getopt examples on the web. Is there anything that you're having problems with? (I assume you've already discovered `getopt_long` for the double-dash options.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokenizing the command line into arguments for your program is the responsibility of your shell, not yours. So there's nothing for you to do.

Just put quotation marks around strings that contain spaces, or escape spaces with backslashes on your command line, and your `--foo` value can contain as many spaces as you like.